# intermittent openssl error with nginx on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nginx, openssl

I got intermittent ssl handshake errors with nginx:

```
2015/08/23 08:46:53 [info] 38013#0: *14817 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac) while SSL handshaking, client: 10.203.128.125, server: 0.0.0.0:5989
2015/08/23 09:24:15 [info] 38013#0: *27818 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking, client: 10.203.128.125, server: 0.0.0.0:5989
```

The error rate is pretty low, it is about 1 out of 10000 (based on the error and request in the last 24 ours)

I already upgraded nginx and openssl to the latest version for 14.04.

```
dpkg -l | egrep "ssl|nginx"
ii  libflac8:amd64                   1.3.0-2                               amd64        Free Lossless Audio Codec - runtime C library
ii  libgnutls-openssl27:amd64        2.12.23-12ubuntu2.1                   amd64        GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
ii  libssl-dev:amd64                 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15                    amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
ii  libssl1.0.0:amd64                1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15                    amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  nginx                            1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3                      all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
ii  nginx-common                     1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3                      all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
ii  nginx-core                       1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3                      amd64        nginx web/proxy server (core version)
ii  openssl                          1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15                    amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
ii  ssl-cert                         1.0.33                                all          simple debconf wrapper for OpenSSL
```

The client is SCVMM 2012 R2.

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score -1):

After we disabled TLS1.2. The SSL error is gone.
Here is the configuration in nginx after the change:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1;
ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Comment: still continues to happen with me